# Access (OleDb) Parameter Prompt Order

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb, jet

I know when using Access (or OleDb in general) it is important to provide the parameters in the right order, even if you name them, as they are always picked up by their order, regardless of name.

However in this query:

`SELECT Comments.ID, Users.Nom, CommentsHelpfulness.Helpful
    FROM (Comments INNER JOIN Users
    ON Comments.UserID = Users.ID)
    LEFT JOIN CommentsHelpfulness
    ON (CommentsHelpfulness.CommentID = Comments.ID
    AND (CommentsHelpfulness.UserID = [enter userid]))
    WHERE (Comments.GameID = [enter gameid])`

why does Access prompt me for the gameid, before it prompts me for the userid? It turns out using this in my asp.net website, I also have to add the gameid first.

How is the order actually determined, in which I have to add the parameters? I thought it's just left to right. (I don't want to know how to change the order, I'm really just interested in how it is determined)

Comment: If you moved the parameter for userid to the WHERE, you would get left to right, but you have a mixed bag here. To control the order, look at this article: http://blogannath.blogspot.com/2010/02/microsoft-access-tips-tricks-parameter.html (search for string 'In general, the order in')

Comment: Controlling the order is helpful, but I would still like to know what determines the order if you don't change it artificially. Your link says "the order in which users are prompted for query parameters is the same order in which the parameters are encountered in the query from beginning to end", but that's not the case here. Do Parameters in WHERE always go before the ones in JOIN conditions? Or does it have something to do with the brackets?

Comment: I don't know the facts about the order, but have learned it can change based on if using subqueries (asks subs before main); thus seems to make sense it would prompt for 'Where' parameters before a join.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that OleDB ignores parameter *names* and requires that parameters must be declared in the exact order in which they appear in the SQL command text. However, when you run a saved parameter query from within the Access application itself you are *not* using OleDb; you are (implicitly) using DAO and DAO *does* pay attention to parameter names.

Therefore, the order in which Access prompts you for the parameters is strictly a matter of preference for you or your users. If you want to define a specific order in which the prompts occur you can use a PARAMETERS clause like this:

```sql
PARAMETERS MinAccounts Long, SelectedPosition Text ( 255 );
SELECT Agents.*
FROM Agents
WHERE (((Agents.Position)=[SelectedPosition]) 
    AND ((Agents.[Number of Accounts])>=[MinAccounts]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However what I am really interested in knowing is how the order is actually determined, when you do not artificially change it using e.g. the PARAMETERS command.